# Store symmetric keys in Java Card

Tags: cryptography, javacard, key-management

I am working on an applet which has to share some keys of type `AESKey` with different terminals. The thing is I don't know in advance how many terminals it will have to handle.

As there is no structure like `HashTable` in Java Card, it's getting complicated. I can still fix an upper bound and instanciate as much objects `AESKey` but I would like to search for another way to do.

I thought I could do something with byte arrays, but is it a bad practice to store keys in `byte[]`?

I think the answer is yes and it is only recommanded to store it in transient arrays to make computations. Otherwise, I don't understand the role of `AESKey` objects. Just want to be sure.

Comment: I think you urgently should be looking at what *key derivation* is.

Comment: Indeed, but if I consider that the keys in question are all derived from a master key, I still have to store the messages related. As we can instanciate byte/short arrays in Java Card it sounds more reasonable. But to ensure the same level security, should these messages have the same length that keys? Thanks

Comment: You can derive the key using the terminal ID and store the result in a  transient array and then set the value of a transient key to that value. Of course you would need to delete the derived key immediately. Hmm, Java Card should probably have a KDF class that sets the value of a symmetric key. Food for thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important security-relevant data like keys and PINs shall always be stored in the therefore designated objects from the Javacard API, e.g. `AESKey`.
 The smartcard operating system will perform additional internal operations to protect there values from leaking.
 If you don't know how many terminals the card will encounter you could encapsulate the Keys in an Object which is part of a linked list:

```
class KeyElement{
   KeyElement next;
   AESKey key;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the solution you propose. Could you describe it more precisely? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, so supposing that I assign an ID to each terminal, I can add a value `short id` to make the association. I don't know why but I didn't think about redefining linked list in Java Card. I suppose that if I have a lot of keys (like a thousand?) it could take a certain time to browse the entire list but I will bench it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Raoul722 if you had a lot of keys (like a thousand), you will probably run out of persistent memory. You should definitely define an upper bound for key count and recycle old AESKey with new content (`isUsed` flag), otherwise you will get into troubles with maintaining such a linked list.

Comment: in both performance and storage this is not optimal but we lack further inforation. key derivation is one point, caching or reordering a list is another, recycling yet another

Comment: Thanks for tips. I will anyway bench the differents solutions during next days and tell you how it results.

Comment: I tried to test it but I encountered some problems described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698283/linkedlist-in-java-card ... Thanks in advance if you can take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible to store key values in a `byte[]` with some 'unknown level of security' by using the following scheme:

Store only wrapped (i.e. encrypted) values of the key in the persistent byte array using some *persistent wrapping key*.

Prior to the key use, unwrap the desired key using the same *wrapping key* into a *transient key object*. Then use it at will.

Advantage: Probably more memory efficient than the 'many `AESKey` objects approach'.

Drawback: It is quite weird. **I would do my best not to implement it this way.**

Desclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.

Desclaimer 2: Of course the most reasonable way is to use key derivation as Maarten Bodewes noted...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, creating `AESKey` array is possible in Java Card. I thought that only byte arrays (`byte[]`) were authorized but no.

So nothing forbids me to declare an `AESKey` array (`AESKey[]`) if I consider that I have to fix an upperbound to limit the number of keys in my applet.